# Ordering event data

Tags: mysql

I have a table which holds event data. The structure is the following

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (`id` int, 
                 `start` datetime, 
                 `end` datetime default null, 
                 `evt` varchar(20), 
                 `sequence` int);
```

But it turns out that data is not coming in the correct order every time. 
The correct order is decided by the following rules:
 1. Every event belongs in a session. You can't have an EventStart, EventEnd outside a SessionStart, SessionEnd.
 2. Each session starts with a `SessionStart` ending with `SessionEnd`. 
 3. An EventStart cannot appear later than an EventEnd.
 4. The xStart, xEnd is matched using the starting time
 5. The order of events and sessions is decided by time and sequence.

In every session there are a lot of events `EventStart`, `EventEnd`. Ideally we would expect them to happen in the following order:

```
 1. SessionStart - 12 - 2018-02-10 15:50:00
 2. EventStart   -  0 - 2018-02-10 15:51:00
 3. EventEnd     -  2 - 2018-02-10 15:51:00 - 2018-02-10 15:52:00
 4. EventStart   -  0 - 2018-02-10 15:52:00
 5. EventEnd     -  3 - 2018-02-10 15:52:00 - 2018-02-10 15:53:00
 6. SessionEnd   - 13 - 2018-02-10 15:50:00 - 2018-02-10 15:55:00
```

But what if I get something like the following

```
 1. EventStart   -  0 - 2018-02-10 15:51:00
 2. EventEnd     -  2 - 2018-02-10 15:51:00 - 2018-02-10 15:52:00
 3. EventStart   -  0 - 2018-02-10 15:52:00
 4. EventEnd     -  3 - 2018-02-10 15:52:00 - 2018-02-10 15:53:00
 5. SessionEnd   - 12 - 2018-02-10 15:50:00 - 2018-02-10 15:55:00
 6. SessionStart - 11 - 2018-02-10 15:50:00
```

I want to be able to collect multiple sessions with the correct order. Is this possible using a single query?

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ipLSGJd5Pqzy1VBGXKx9Mv/2

Comment: In the sql fiddle data, how do you identify the event id of  a particular row. There is no such information in the sample data .

Comment: I cannot see any data in this fiddle.

Comment: @P.Salmon SQL fiddle is unrealiable. I have copied to db fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ipLSGJd5Pqzy1VBGXKx9Mv/0

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya The `SessionEnd` has the same start with `SessionStart`.

Comment: There can be multiple SessionEnd; how does someone know which SessionStart it belongs to

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya SessionStart sequence is SessionEnd sequence minus 1.

Comment: Do we assume that all evenstart and eventend evts belong in sessionstart/session end blocks based on start? AND an eventstart cannot happen before another eventend and these will occur in id order?

Comment: @P.Salmon All `EventStart`, `EventEnd` events belong to a session. But the order is not guaranteed. Only thing that is solid is start, end time. So someone will need to find which events belong to a session based on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This proved to be a difficult problem to solve using SQL only and I ended up doing a lot of changes.

What I did was to add another column named sessionId.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (`id` int, 
                 `start` datetime, 
                 `end` datetime default null, 
                 `sessionId` int,
                 `evt` varchar(20), 
                 `sequence` int);
```

This column gets populated by a background worker and assigns the same sessionId for every event inside the session period.

Then I can just use the following

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE evt = 'SessionStart' AND sessionId = 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE evt in('EventStart', 'EventEnd') AND sessionId = 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE evt = 'SessionEnd' AND sessionId = 1
```

This could be further simplified because the newer devices that generate events will also include event generation timestamp and sessionId for every event.